# Clicking on the featured job in the app results in 404 Not Found

Tags: bug, jobs, mobile-app

When I open the mobile app (on android) and try to click on the featured job listing listed as "earlier today" the browser that opens shows a 404 Not Found.

https://clc.stackoverflow.com/jobs/131952/net-senior-developer-backend-mountain-warehouse-ltd?an=4xSwUNqZb3rFg5OBwcmd04EBCBhBxDUbBgbpOh4mhogWZgYGdgamAwZVqlapj2PsGYK0A9yLtX5y6h4CAA&cr=230488&ct=0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fjobs%2F131952%2Fnet-senior-developer-backend-mountain-warehouse-ltd&sig=CctiuKJ0WuZP7Q

The job can be found correctly here:
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/131952/net-senior-developer-backend-mountain-warehouse-ltd?a=zkLBYbJHokgqPQpq&searchTerm=net-senior-developer-backend-mountain-warehouse-ltd

Comment: Cheers @Cai. I've updated the tags on that one, and will close this one.